# Calculate datetime with current datetime to get the time left

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the following value, which I'm getting from my database `2014-08-29 04:37:36` I want to calculate this value within current date time.

Like my above value is `2014-08-29 04:37:36` but I want to show `3 days left` instead `2014-08-29 04:37:36`. If my value is `2014-08-23 04:37:36` it should show `-2 days left`.

Whatever my value is, i want to calculate it and show the time left, if it expired than it should show a minus sign as I explained above. Can anyone help me please!!

This question is much simpler and different than the references given to mark as duplicate. My question is clear and simple, not complex to the references given by HAL9000, Boann, karthikr, amphetamachine, Shankar Damodaran. Also the references are misleading my question.

Comment: Have you done something on this? Is so, please post that code

Comment: those are much complicated.

Comment: @Boann Please read the question again since your reference has nothing do do with this question.

Comment: @HAL9000 Your reference is a misleading post as well.

Comment: Im requesting to mark my question to not duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the snippet below

```
<?php
$datestr = "2014-08-28 19:10:18";
$date = strtotime($datestr);

$diff = $date - time();         
$days = floor($diff / (60 * 60 * 24));  
$hours = round(($diff - $days * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60));

echo "$days days $hours hours left";
?>
```

Output:

```
3 days 9 hours left
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/qSBYhJ)

Comment: @Sahed I know; glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP DateTime::diff function described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Quick example:

```
<?php

$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = date_create('2014-12-10');

$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);

echo $diff->format('%R%a days');
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/oTyRwQ)

The nice thing about this code is that you can change the return string format easily using [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: Actually; PHP < 5.3, but I don't think answers should be discarded because they don't work with older versions of PHP, especially when that older release has been released 5 years ago.

Comment: Of course not ;) just wanted to point it out, since I had the same issue a few weeks ago on a project running on PHP < 5.2 I guess

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$dateNow = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$getDate = new DateTime("2014-08-29 04:37:36");
$diff= $getDate->diff($dateNow);
$return = $diff->days;
if($dateNow>$getDate)
  echo "-".$return." Days Left";
else
  echo $return." Days Left";
```

Comment: Just a note; it doesn't work on PHP < 5.2 (I guess)

Comment: May be, I test it PHP 5.5 :(

Comment: Same as above: Actually; PHP < 5.3, but I don't think answers should be discarded because they don't work with older versions of PHP, especially when that older release has been released 5 years ago

Comment: So, as has been pointed by @RichardBernards ('cause I wasn't sure) usage of `DateTime` is version ( PHP >= 5.3) dependent